# Get PowerShell command output as a variable in bat (cmd) script

Tags: powershell, windows-command-prompt, batch, variables

I'm trying to get FQDN of a host in some .cmd file. We have disjointed AD domain so `"@echo %COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN%"` does not work. I mean it works, but returns wrong value.

The solution I ended up with is 
    `powershell.exe -noninteractive -command[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($env:computerName)).HostName`

It works fine in the command line. I'm trying to get it in a variable in my cmd file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (\`powershell.exe -noninteractive -command     
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($env:computerName)).HostName\`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
```

But getting the following error:
).HostName`) was unexpected at this time.

I understand that something should be screened since both cmd and powershell are parsing this line, but do not know what  to screen and how.
How to make this get to work?

Comment: Quote the right-parens with hat: `^)^)`. Also the backquotes should not be preceded by backslashes; I assume/hope that is an artifact of trying to markdown for Stack.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape parenthesis inside *the subject* when using `FOR \F`

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell.exe -noninteractive -command [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName^(^($env:computerName^)^).HostName`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)

ECHO %var%
```

Comment: this works, but not on the command line. I tried to do it on the command line first, but that didnt work. Once I did it in a bat file, worked flawlessly

Comment: To make this work in a command line, you must put only one % in front of the F variable.  %% in a batch file.